# In XSD, how to restrict enumeration by attribute value?

Tags: xml, xsd, xsd-1.1

In the example xml/xsd below, when the user enters a value for AnimalCategories, I want the enumeration in AnimalBreeds to only allow the appropriate values.  For example, if the user enters Cat, then the valid choices for AnimalBreeds should only be Siamese and Persian.  I have reviewed posts regarding assertion and alternatives available in xsd 1.1, but I can't see how to apply it to my specific need.

Any ideas would be greatly appreciated.

[image: Validation]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AnimalsData xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="AnimalsData.xsd">
    <AnimalData AnimalCategories="Dog" AnimalBreeds="Boxer"/>
    <AnimalData AnimalCategories="Cat" AnimalBreeds="Siamese"/>
</AnimalsData>


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType name="AnimalsDataType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="AnimalData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AnimalDataType">
        <xs:attribute ref="AnimalCategories" use="required"/>
        <xs:attribute ref="AnimalBreeds" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AnimalCategoriesType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Dog"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Cat"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AnimalBreedsType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Boxer"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Rottweiler"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Siamese"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Persian"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:element name="AnimalsData" type="AnimalsDataType"/>
    <xs:element name="AnimalData" type="AnimalDataType"/>
    <xs:attribute name="AnimalCategories" type="AnimalCategoriesType"/>
    <xs:attribute name="AnimalBreeds" type="AnimalBreedsType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

Comment: You realize that expressing your constraint in XSD does not itself guarantee anything about "when a user picks a value" or "only show[ing] the appropriate values", right?

Comment: Of course... I updated my post accordingly.  I was just referring to the auto complete per validation of the associated schema in an editor like XMLSply.  See attached image.

Answer (score 4):

If you can enumerate the categories and their breeds, the simplest way to make this checkable is to use the names of categories (and optionally also breeds) as element names, not as attribute values.

**If you do this just for categories, but not breeds**, your XML might take a form like this:

```
<AnimalsData>
  <Dog Breeds="Boxer"/>
  <Cat Breeds="Siamese"/>
</AnimalsData>
```

The elements Dog and Cat are made substitutable for AnimalData (which you may wish to make abstract, unless you expect some non-dog, non-cat instances; your current schema says you do not expect any such), and their types are derived from that of AnimalData.  For Dog, the necessary machinery looks like this:

```
<xs:complexType name="Dog">
  <xs:complexContent>
    <xs:restriction base="AnimalDataType">
      <xs:attribute name="AnimalBreeds" 
        use="required" 
        type="DogBreedsType"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:complexContent>
</xs:complexType>

<xs:simpleType name="DogBreedsType">
  <xs:restriction base="AnimalBreedsType">
    <xs:enumeration value="Boxer"/>
    <xs:enumeration value="Rottweiler"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:element name="Dog" type="Dog" substitutionGroup="AnimalData"/>
```

Cat works the same way.  And of course, since the attribute AnimalCategories is now redundant with the element type name, we've dropped it:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnimalDataType">
  <xs:attribute name="AnimalBreeds" use="required"
                type="AnimalBreedsType"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

**A more thorough re-thinking** moves the breeds from attribute values to element names, as well.  The XML will look like this:

```
<AnimalsData>
  <Dog><Boxer/></Dog>
  <Cat><Siamese/></Cat>
</AnimalsData>
```

The schema would look something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:complexType name="AnimalsDataType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="AnimalData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AnimalDataType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="Breed"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:complexType name="Dog">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="AnimalDataType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="CanineBreed"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="Cat">
    <xs:complexContent>
      <xs:restriction base="AnimalDataType">
        <xs:sequence>
          <xs:element ref="FelineBreed"/>
        </xs:sequence>
      </xs:restriction>
    </xs:complexContent>
  </xs:complexType>

  <xs:element name="AnimalsData" type="AnimalsDataType"/>
  <xs:element name="AnimalData" type="AnimalDataType" abstract="true"/>
  <xs:element name="Dog" type="Dog" substitutionGroup="AnimalData"/>
  <xs:element name="Cat" type="Cat" substitutionGroup="AnimalData"/>

  <xs:element name="Breed" abstract="true">
    <xs:complexType><xs:sequence/></xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="CanineBreed" abstract="true" 
              substitutionGroup="Breed"/>
  <xs:element name="FelineBreed" abstract="true" 
              substitutionGroup="Breed"/>
  <xs:element name="Boxer" substitutionGroup="CanineBreed"/>
  <xs:element name="Rottweiler" substitutionGroup="CanineBreed"/>
  <xs:element name="Siamese" substitutionGroup="FelineBreed"/>
  <xs:element name="Persian" substitutionGroup="FelineBreed"/>

</xs:schema>
```

**To use conditional types**, define category-specific subtypes of `AnimalDataType` (in the example below, these are `Dog` and `Cat`); to constrain the breeds you'll also need category-specific subtypes of `AnimalBreedsType`.  Then use `xs:alternative` within the element declaration for `AnimalData` to assign the correct restricted type to the element.  The schema as a whole looks like this.  (I have made the two attributes local to `AnimalData` because it confuses me to have them be global.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" 
           elementFormDefault="qualified" 
           attributeFormDefault="unqualified" 
           vc:minVersion="1.1">
  <xs:complexType name="AnimalsDataType">
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="AnimalData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:complexType name="AnimalDataType">
    <xs:attribute ref="AnimalCategories" use="required"/>
    <xs:attribute ref="AnimalBreeds" use="required"/>
  </xs:complexType>
  <xs:simpleType name="AnimalCategoriesType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Dog"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Cat"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="AnimalBreedsType">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:enumeration value="Boxer"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Rottweiler"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Siamese"/>
      <xs:enumeration value="Persian"/>
    </xs:restriction>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:element name="AnimalsData" type="AnimalsDataType"/>
  <xs:element name="AnimalData" type="AnimalDataType"/>
  <xs:attribute name="AnimalCategories" type="AnimalCategoriesType"/>
  <xs:attribute name="AnimalBreeds" type="AnimalBreedsType"/>
</xs:schema>
```

**To use assertions**, it suffices to add the following assertions to the declaration for `AnimalDataType`:

```
<xs:complexType name="AnimalDataType">
  <xs:attribute ref="AnimalCategories" use="required"/>
  <xs:attribute ref="AnimalBreeds" use="required"/>

  <xs:assert test="if (@AnimalCategories='Dog')
    then @AnimalBreeds = ('Boxer', 'Rottweiler')
    else true()"/>
  <xs:assert test="if (@AnimalCategories='Cat')
      then @AnimalBreeds = ('Siamese', 'Persian')
      else true()"/>
</xs:complexType>
```

Note that all four of these variations encode the same information about the correlation between category and breed, but the information is more accessible to other software in some cases than in others.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use alternative types, you can find below another example of your schema.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:vc="http://www.w3.org/2007/XMLSchema-versioning" elementFormDefault="qualified"
    attributeFormDefault="unqualified" vc:minVersion="1.1">
    <xs:complexType name="AnimalsDataType">
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element ref="AnimalData" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="AnimalDataType">
        <xs:attribute ref="AnimalCategories" use="required"/>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="DogDataType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="AnimalDataType">
                <xs:attribute name="AnimalBreeds" type="DogBreedsType" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:complexType name="CatDataType">
        <xs:complexContent>
            <xs:extension base="AnimalDataType">
                <xs:attribute name="AnimalBreeds" type="CatBreedsType" use="required"/>
            </xs:extension>
        </xs:complexContent>
    </xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleType name="AnimalCategoriesType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Dog"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Cat"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>
    <xs:simpleType name="DogBreedsType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Boxer"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Rottweiler"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:simpleType name="CatBreedsType">
        <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
            <xs:enumeration value="Siamese"/>
            <xs:enumeration value="Persian"/>
        </xs:restriction>
    </xs:simpleType>

    <xs:element name="AnimalsData" type="AnimalsDataType"/>
    <xs:element name="AnimalData" type="AnimalDataType">
        <xs:alternative test="@AnimalCategories='Dog'" type="DogDataType"/>
        <xs:alternative test="@AnimalCategories='Cat'" type="CatDataType"/>
    </xs:element>

    <xs:attribute name="AnimalCategories" type="AnimalCategoriesType"/>
</xs:schema>
```